# Rust's ownership: How to break implementation code into discrete methods?

Tags: rust, sdl-2, ownership

I'm still relatively new to Rust and often enough it feels like I need to "shove-in' entire code blocks (from discrete methods) into the same code block because either:

- a) I don't master Rust's ownership **<--- which is mighty likely**
- b) there's no other way.

A random example I found online: https://github.com/Rust-SDL2/rust-sdl2/blob/master/examples/game-of-life.rs pretty much demonstrate what I mean.

In this example, (although the duplication is trivial) I feel that a method to draw a square of a given color might have been used rather than duplicating such code 3 times.

This is pretty much exactly the challenge I often face. Rather than creating a method such as `draw_square(&self, &mut WindowCanvas, color: Color)` I have to shove-in the entire body of such method because the Rust's ownership feature won't allow me breaking my code into discrete methods and pass that `texture_canvas` around because of usage of `&self` or that `&mut canvas` from closure.

For example, I can't manage to find the proper syntax to write such construct:

```rust
        // Set the render target to the texture
        self.canvas.with_texture_canvas(&mut self.texture, |texture_canvas| {

              // Clear the virtual canvas
              texture_canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RGB(255, 255, 255));
              texture_canvas.clear();

              // Rendering content on the virtual canvas
              self.draw_cells(texture_canvas);
              self.draw_path(texture_canvas);
              self.draw_extra_widgets(texture_canvas);

        }).unwrap();
```

**EDIT**
For completeness, here is another example (probably a typical proper one) where drawing to canvas is kept to minimum and game objects are fully decoupled from SDL/Drawing:
https://sunjay.dev/learn-game-dev/ecs-refactor-multiple-modules.html

Comment: In the SDL example, extracting a function to draw the squares is perfectly possible but the "yellow square" has different dimensions than the other two (mod factors of 4 and 9 rather than 7 and 5), as such I would assume whoever created the example didn't consider the gain to be sufficient for a function with 5 parameters which may not be easy to name compared to just duplicating the snippet.

Comment: The problem with your version is that once you've captured part of an object mutably (`&mut self.texture`) you can't refer to the entire object anymore, as this would break the rules of R^W, as you could have concurrent unique and shared references, which is against the rules of the language. This is less about ownership, and more about borrowing rules.

Comment: The solutions are to use different patterns than those you learned from "promiscuously mutable" languages e.g.: split the object into more tractable sub-objects, actually split the borrows and use utility functions (it's not like methods are special, free functions are perfectly fine in rust), move content back and forth using `std::mem::take` or `replace`, or as last resort use inner mutability to bypass the issue.

Comment: It's also worth considering `Arc<RwLock<X>>` to wrap mutable data structures if you need to mutate this in several places.

Comment: What Masklinn said. It does sound like perhaps you're keeping too much state bundled together when it shouldn't be bundled so closely. Rust is not an OOP language, and trying to do the OOP thing of bundling together every single piece of data along with every single dependency into a single data structure is only going to bring you pain.

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks for such quick answers! I feel that my Rust proficiency is not quite high enough to fully grasp your answers. Can you point to concrete examples? I wasn’t able myself to find such examples. I found that GameOfLife example but it basically « shove-in » the entire drawing code within that block.

Comment: @cdhowie Oh! This is definitively something I totally didn't get from my readings and experimenting :-/ --- and Yes, it does bring a lot of (what I feel) unnecessary pain :-/

Comment: Rust does support OO, despite the prevalence of comments on stackoverflow and other platforms. It's as much an OO language as C++, but it takes a lot of learning to adapt to its idiosyncracies and very strict rules.